# how to get numbers under numbers in LaTeX

Tags: formatting

So, I have an equation and I need that the matrix  near equation be written like that in LaTeX

> ```
>    0 2 0 
> A= 0 0 5   
>    0 0 4
> ```

But I get that:

0 2 0

`some equation` A= 0 0 5

0 0 4

```
                                         0 2 0
How get this result?: `some equation` A= 0 0 5
                                         0 0 4
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  please help us understand how you got the result you did by providing a small compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that demonstrates your result.  i think i can guess what happened, but that's all it would be -- a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options. The "matrix" environments make use of package `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  A =
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 5 \\
    0 & 0 & 4
  \end{array}
  = \begin{matrix}
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 5 \\
    0 & 0 & 4
  \end{matrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 5 \\
    0 & 0 & 4
  \end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 5 \\
    0 & 0 & 4
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]